# How do I calculate the force necessary to accelerate a point on a rigid body by a certain amount?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

Given a rigid body of uniform density with moment of inertia tensor $I$ and mass $m$, I'm trying to figure out how much force $F_p$ I need to apply at point $\vec p$ so that *that* point accelerates by a known $\vec a_p$. The direction of the force is given, so I really just need the magnitude.

I know that the center of mass $\vec c$ of the rigid body will accelerate by $\vec a_c = \vec F_p / m$ and that $\vec F_p$ will produce a torque around $\vec c$ given by $\vec \tau = \vec F_p \times \vec r = I \vec \alpha$ (where $\vec r = \vec p - \vec c$). So I *think* I could express $\vec a_p$ as $$\vec a_p = \vec a_c + \vec \alpha \times \vec r = \vec F_p/m+(\vec F_p \times \vec r)I^{-1} \times \vec r$$
However, I don't know how to untangle $F_p$ from here or if there's another way I should be calculating this. I'm a programmer, not really a physics expert, so I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Rev 0

What you are looking for is the dynamic effective mass of a body along a direction and through a point. The is the same calculation used to find out contact impulses for 3D bodies.

This dynamic mass is found as follows

$$ m^\star_p = \frac{1}{ \frac{1}{m}+\left(\hat{n}\times\overline{c}\right)\cdot\mathrm{I}^{-1}_c\left(\hat{n}\times\overline{c}\right) } $$

where $m$ is the mass of the body, $\mathrm{I}_c$ is the 3×3 mass moment of inertia tensor about the center of mass and along the inertial frame directions, $\hat{n}$ is the direction of the force or impulse action, and $\overline{c}$ is the relative position of the center of mass to the contact point.

In 2D the above becomes

$$ m^\star_p = \frac{1}{ \tfrac{1}{m} + \tfrac{d^2}{I_c} } $$

where $d$ is the *perpendicular* distance between the line of action and the center of mass.

Once this is known then $\overline{F}_p = m^\star_p \, \overline{a}_p$.

### Rev 1

I realized that the above is applicable only if the direction of force is specified (like in a contact). But in your case, $\overline{F}_p$ could be in any direction, which makes the problem a bit simpler.

Consider the 3×3 mass matrix

$$ \mathrm{M}_p = \left[\tfrac{1}{m} \bf{1}-[\overline{c}\times]\mathrm{I}_{c}^{-1}[\overline{c}\times]\right]^{-1} $$

<sub>Here $[\overline{c}\times]$ is the 3×3 [cross product matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication) defined as</sub>

$$ \overline{c} = \pmatrix{x\\y\\z} $$
$$ [\overline{c}\times] = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -z & y \\ z & 0 & -x \\ -y & x & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

then I can show that

$$ \overline{F}_{p} =\mathrm{M}_p\,\overline{a}_{p} $$

In 2D when $\overline{c} = \pmatrix{c_x \\ c_y}$ then

$$ \mathrm{M}_p = \begin{bmatrix} \tfrac{1}{m} + \tfrac{c_y^2}{I_c} & -\tfrac{c_x c_y}{I_c} \\ - \tfrac{c_x c_y}{I_c} & \tfrac{1}{m} + \tfrac{c_x^2}{I_c} \end{bmatrix}^{-1} $$

---

#### Proof

Consider the equations of motion of the offset force $\overline{F}_p$

$$\begin{aligned}\overline{F}_{p} & =m\,\left(\overline{a}_{p}+\overline{\alpha}\times\overline{c}\right)\\
\overline{F}_{p}\times\overline{c} & =\mathrm{I}_{c}\overline{\alpha}
\end{aligned}$$

Solving the 2nd equation and plugging into the first one yields

$$\begin{aligned}\overline{F}_{p}&=m\,\overline{a}_{p}+\overline{c}\times m\left(\mathrm{I}_{c}^{-1}\left(\overline{c}\times\overline{F}_{p}\right)\right)\\\overline{F}_{p}-\overline{c}\times m\left(\mathrm{I}_{c}^{-1}\left(\overline{c}\times\overline{F}_{p}\right)\right)&=m\,\overline{a}_{p}\\ m\left[\tfrac{1}{m}-\overline{c}\times\mathrm{I}_{c}^{-1}\overline{c}\times\right]\overline{F}_{p}&=m\, \overline{a}_{p}\\ \overline{F}_{p}&=\left[\tfrac{1}{m}-[\overline{c}\times]\mathrm{I}_{c}^{-1}[\overline{c}\times]\right]^{-1}\overline{a}_{p}\end{aligned}$$

#### Addendum

The two scenarios above are related with the following expression

$$ m^\star_p = \frac{ 1} {\hat{n}^\top \mathrm{M}_p^{-1} \hat{n} } $$

Comment: Perfect. This is just what I needed! In my case the direction of the force _is_ specified, so I'll probably have to use Rev 0. But this definitely gets me on the right track, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for an answer for the 2D case.

In general, the direction of the force isn't the same as the direction of the desired acceleration, if the line along which the force is applied doesn't pass through the center of mass.

I ended up with this formula for the force vector:

```
force = (acc + inv_angular_mass * (point /dot/ acc) / inv_mass * point) /
    (inv_mass + inv_angular_mass * point.len_sq())
```

Where:

- `point` is the position of the point being accelerated, relative to the center of mass,
- `acc` is the desired acceleration vector at this point,
- `inv_mass` is `1 / mass`, and `inv_angular_mass` is `1 / moment_of_inertia`.
- `*` for vectors is element-wise multiplication (in `point * acc`),
- `a /dot/ b` is the dot product,
- `A.len_sq()` is `A.x*A.x + A.y*A.y`.

This formula likely needs the angles to be expressed in radians.

This was obtained from [Mathics3](https://mathics.org/) by putting an inverse formula into it (acceleration from force), then solving for `force` and manually rewriting into a shorter and cleaner expression:

```
p={px,py}; f={fx,fy}; v={vx,vy}
sol = Solve[Thread[Normalize[Cross[p]]*(px*fy-py*fx)*InvAngMass+f*InvMass==v],f]
Simplify[sol] /. x_*y_+x_*z_->x*(y+z)
(* Now try to rewrite it manually *)
manual = (v+InvAngMass*p*Total[p*v]/InvMass)/(InvMass+InvAngMass*(p.p))
Simplify[manual]
(* Compare the results by eye to make sure they are the same *)
```

---

Alternatively, you can fix the direction of the force, but then you can't control the exact acceleration vector, only its projection on some direction.

```
force_value = acc_value / (inv_angular_mass * (point /cross/ force_dir) *
    (point /cross/ acc_dir) + inv_mass * (force_dir /dot/ acc_dir))
```

Where:

- `acc_dir` is the direction of the desired acceleration, and `acc_value` is the projection of the acceleration on it. `acc_dir` should be normalized (or `acc_value` should be *multiplied* by its length, since this method ensures `dot(acc, acc_dir) == acc_value`),
- `force_dir` is the desired force direction, not normalized. Multiplying it by the resulting `force` value gives the final force vector.
- `a /cross/ b` is the Z-component of the cross-product, `a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x`.
  Inference in Mathics3:

```
p={px,py}; fd={fdx,fdy}; f={fx,fy}=fd*force; v={vx,vy}; n={nx,ny}
sol = Solve[Thread[(Normalize[Cross[p]]*(px*fy-py*fx)*InvAngMass+f*InvMass).n==speed],force]
(* Manually rewriting the denominator into a vector form *)
Expand[((InvAngMass*(px*fdy-py*fdx)*(px*ny-py*nx)+InvMass*Total[fd*n]))]
```